# ASP.NET insert related fields

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010

I am new at asp .net dev and I was playing with the ObjectDataSource and DetailsView, so I have the following problem:

My database has two tables:

hospital - Clients

With foreign key in client for the key of hospital (client has an hospital) 
and I want in the insert of a new client to get a dropdown list of hospitals already available in database.

I've tested the insert and it's working fine but I couldn't get the dropdown list. 
I'm using only the visual studion interface for this I'm not changing any codes.

Comment: Paste the code you used to populate dropdown list.

Comment: i've used objectdatasource who get data from DataSet i don't use any code in the background i want to use the visual studio built-in features for this

Comment: share source code...

Comment: @Learning it has been 5 five years what are you doing in old posts  ? even i don't understand what i wrote after all this time XD

Comment: @zerzer, Oh, i missed on date i though it was new question